# What is the proper way to use v-select ,item-text and item-value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

This is the response of api i call

[image]
from another view.

[image]

I am storing the api result lets say in `result = [];`.

I am creating a drop down list using **v-select** with `:items="result"`.

How should i write for `item-text` and `item-value` if i want `services.name` to be the text shown on dropdown list and `services._id` will be stored in an variable using **v-model** , `services._id` as a `item-value`.

I can't seem to figure out these nested properties.

Comment: Do you want to show all services in the v select or the service from one object of the array ?

Comment: @RenaudC5
name of all the services in v-select item-text and corresponding id be the item-value which i will pass to local variable with v-model

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do is retrieve all the services from all the sub arrays through a `computed` property.

Then you will only have one array of object (instead of an array of arrays through the property services) and you can specify the `item-text` and `item-value` properties !

Here is an example

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => {
    return {
      currentItem: null,
      items: [{
          services: [
            {_id: 1,name: 'foo'},
            {_id: 2, name: 'bar'}
          ]
        },
        {
          services: [
            {_id: 1,name: 'foo'}, 
            {_id: 3, name: 'baz'} 
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    allServices(){
      return this.items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        curr.services.forEach(service => {
          if(!acc.find(x => x._id === service._id)) acc.push(service)
        })
        return acc
      }, [])
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css" />

<div id="app" data-app>
  currentItem : {{currentItem}}
  <v-select v-model="currentItem" :items="allServices" item-text="name" item-value="_id"></v-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `slots` of the `v-select` to customize  the shown data:

```
<v-select
    label="Services"
    v-model="customVar"
    :items="result"
    item-value="_id"
    item-text="name"
    return-object
  >
    <template v-slot:selection="data">
      {{ data.item.name }}
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item="data">
      {{ data.item.name }}
    </template>
  </v-select>
```

Also you could use as shown above `return-object`:

> Changes the selection behavior to return the object directly rather than the value specified with item-value

So you could choose wich variables you use from the selected object